# How does the Oracle CEP turn a command into Event？

Tags: oracle, complex-event-processing

Take an INSERT command for example, when I insert something into a table, how can the Oracle CEP know what I have done?

I have read the document about the Oracle CEP, but it's too brief. I know only that event is represented as POJO in Oracle.

Does the Oracle CEP just parse the INSERT command and try to find whether it matches some event class in Oracle?

Or is there any difference between CEP and Active Database?

Comment: CEP is a network based application for processing *messages*.  It is nothing to do with the database (although a database can produce a stream of messages which CEP could pocess).  Oracle may have begun as a database vendor but that was 35 years ago.  Now they have offerings across the entire software stack.

Comment: @APC That is to say, the notion of Event has nothing to do with that in Active Database?

Comment: Yea.  One of IT's (many) problems is that the same relative handful of terms   is used to mean different things, depending on context.